# Dishwasher leaving residue, needing frequent cleaning

Tags: kitchens, appliances, dishwasher

I'm looking for any ideas about how to get my dishwasher working better. Right now I need to take it apart and clean out a filter each week, but this filter is not easily removed (~8 screws) and did not ever need cleaning in the past. Even after running the dishwasher empty I have observed this filter getting a bit of gunk in it. After cleaning, it works well and gradually gets more clogged up, by the end of the week there's soapy residue left on the dishes.

Some bad choices made leading up to having this issue:

- running the dishwasher with juicer parts that were packed full of apple pulp, causing the bottom of the dishwasher to be full of standing water and the first time I observed the permanent filter being clogged
- trying different more eco friendly soaps which was the first time we observed dishes not getting clean and soapy residue remaining
- taking apart the dishwasher and noticing one of the gaskets did not fit clearly back into place, I think it's right now but liable to be wrong

Some things I've tried:

- running the dishwasher empty with vinegar
- running the dishwasher empty

The dishwasher is a Frigidaire FPHD2491KF0

Please see the pictures on this post. Appreciate any ideas about things to try!

[image: photo of inside of dishwasher]

above: inside of dishwasher and the problem area

[image: shows grime immediately after running an empty cycle]

above: cleaned the filter, and then ran an empty cycle with vinegar and this grime showed up

[image: grime on the filter]

above: the filter that's difficult to remove, after a week of usage

[image: confusing o ring]

above: confusing o ring, it doesn't seem to sit right in there and its not obvious to me how it should fit

[image: different view of confusing o ring]

above: it seems too big to fit into the groove in there, I regret having taken this apart

[image: under the sink]

above: under the sink, for context

Comment: Do you have a water softener? Is it working? Does it need salt? Try removing the o-ring and placing it in hot water for a few minutes, then re-install without stretching or pulling it.

Comment: The pictures appear to show limescale build-up. This should never happen in a dishwasher. I also can't see anywhere you'd fill the salt [though there's something I can't identify on the left wall], so does it just not have a built-in softener?? Crud, as in the existing answer, is not getting removed. Do you have a Vax [carpet cleaner] you could flush & suck with?

Comment: @Tetsujin agree, but it's hard to see in a picture. When my drain is clogged I get the same white film & speckles, which in a picture is hard to distinguish from limescale. So it could be grime or indeed also limescale.

Comment: Do you clean the little cup thing and the course stainless steel mesh as well?  On my dishwasher the cup thing is the filter that prevents grit from getting into the spray arms.

Comment: @Ecnerwal i do not have a water softener, i don't believe the water here is hard (Portland OR)

Comment: @Tetsujin I assumed the white residue inside the dishwasher is likely soap, I'll have to look into limescale  i'm not famliar with it

Comment: @P2000 i later noticed a bunch of scum on the bottom of the dishwasher where the door hinge is, it gets trapped behind the gasket. i should try to clean it out really well and run it empty

Comment: Soap shouldn't be leaving any residue either - but you've obviously got some kind of blockage, so anything might happen.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger yes I clean the removable filter regularly, it stays pretty clean. maybe gets a little white buildup (possibly same as soap buildup seen elsewhere)

Comment: @Tetsujin 

> Do you have a Vax [carpet cleaner] you could flush & suck with

i have a shop vac, should i use it to suck all the water out of the bottom?

Comment: I had the residue problem on a bosch dishwasher - my problem was that the cup filter wasn't screwed on.  The cup filter looked to be fitting but since it wasn't screwed tightly into place small particles would get around the fine filter and were pumped into the spray arms depositing onto my dishes.  The other thing I'd fix is your dishwasher drain hose, you don't want a loop lower than the connection that pools water and crud and will never fully drain.

Comment: Looking at the underside of your screwed down fine filter I am unclear on how that residue could build up.  Those particles all look larger than the fine filter mesh.

Comment: Third picture looks like hard water deposits. Since it's municipal supply, might be worth asking the supplier if the chemistry has changed, and/or what it is (they should know, in detail.)

Comment: I suspect this is normal.  It's common for a DW to run the drain water backwards briefly at the end of a cycle, to flush the strainer.  Normally the water would go *down* through the strainer, to catch crud from the dishes, then they backflush to clean the strainer.  Wouldn't be that odd for some crud to be picked up in the backwash.

Comment: schpet - yeah, I was just thinking about giving it a good rinse out using something that wasn't going to be using the filters. Maybe even get a pressure washer in there [though that might be splashy;) & drain with the vac, which won't care at all about a bit of crud.

Comment: I live in City of Portland OR.  City water is soft here.  And due to OR regs all dishwasher soap sold here is no phosphate - now.  If you can find some WITH phosphate please tell me!  Your o ring looks water swollen and needs replacement.  I also think you have material stuck in the dishwasher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late to the party but I have the same issue with the same dishwasher and what I found out was that I didn’t have a high loop on my drain hose. I looked at your picture and even though it comes down from a high point like a high loop should, it goes down before it goes up and into the drain. Try feeding your hose back a bit into the cabinetry so that it doesn’t droop before the drain.

Comment: oh WOW @michelle! same issue and same dishwasher – i wonder how many of us there are? i did what you said and ran it a few times and i think it has resolved it?? i also finally heard the sound that it used to make while draining – such a great familiar sound that i haven't heard in a long time. i have just been diligently cleaning my filter after every wash but it looks like i won't need to any more. thanks so much, this is a real gift!

Answer (score 3):

Check the drain hose attachment. The inner diameter is reduced around the nipple and something can be caught there, possibly causing back-wash of drain water.

[image]

Image: https://howtofixit.net/dishwasher-not-draining/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! i pulled this off, some water and a tiny amount of gunk drained out but it didn't look clogged so it doesn't look like drain hose connection under the sink has a clog

Answer (score 2):

**A reservoir of crud must be in there somewhere**

You cleaned all the filters and ran it empty and crud appeared.  That crud was waiting somewhere that you did not clean.  Where could it have been?

Water cycles thru the filter up to the spray arms and out.  Maybe your apple pulp adventure overwhelmed the filter.  Crud entered the spray arms and it is there still.  I could imaging that cleaning out the dishwasher might not include cleaning out the spray arms.

Take them out and take a look.  It should be pretty obvious.  If big chunks are occluding the exit holes then water pressure will be low.  My theory is clearing out these big chunks will allow a few empty runs to clear out whatever else is left along the recirculation circuit.

If you find a bunch of crud in the spray arms please post another fine image so that I might do a victory dance.  If there is nothing in there please quietly ignore this idea and move on to ideas from people with real expertise.

Comment: My thoughts also, a brunch of crud is hiding somewhere deep inside a passage way.  The O ring does seem to be too big, should only maybe go to edge not beyond, They are made to size and not need to stuff in groove.

Comment: @crip659 - I admire how openminded you are as regards  brunch options.

Comment: OP did mention apple pulp, could be used in brunch.  These new fangled typewriters always putting wrong letters in.

Comment: yeah i think there's a bunch of crud on the bottom of the dishwasher where the door swings open, it hides behind the gasket. i'll try cleaning that out well and run it empty again. the part that weirds me out is that this crud ends up in the non-removable filter, instead of the removable filter

Comment: i'll check the spray arms too, i checked them pretty recently though and they seemed to flow freely when i connected them to the tap. whenever i open the dishwasher when it's running they appear to be spraying ok

Answer (score 0):

[image]I’ve taken a picture to show you mine that I realized was just laying on the floor of the cabinet. Someone didn’t install correctly. Hopefully that shows you what I’m talking about. I can’t be 100% sure this is the problem but if everything else seems to be working, what I’ve read is that if there is no high loop you could end up getting backwash of dirty water from your drain.

Comment: This needs to be edited into your other question.